# how to cancel the asynchronous task on back press in activity

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, android-asynctask, onbackpressed

An activity have three fragments. the third fragment has asynchronous task. how to cancel the asynchronous task on back press in activity.

```
public void onBackPressed() {

            android.app.Fragment currentVisibleFragment = getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.container);
            if(currentVisibleFragment != null) {
                String visibleFragmentName = currentVisibleFragment.toString();
                if (visibleFragmentName.contains(LearnToWriteLetterUtils.TAMIL_LEARN_TO_WRITE_FLASHSCREEN)) {

                    Log.d("app finished", "finished");
                    finish();
                } else if (visibleFragmentName.contains(LearnToWriteLetterUtils.TAMIL_LEARN_TO_WRITE_INDEXPAGE)) {
                    Log.d("app finished", "exit");
                    finish();
                } else if (visibleFragmentName.contains(LearnToWriteLetterUtils.TAMIL_LEARN_TO_WRITE_LOADING_SCREEN)){

                    getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, tamilLearnToWriteIndexPage, LearnToWriteLetterUtils.TAMIL_LEARN_TO_WRITE_INDEXPAGE).commit();
                }
            }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This:

```
 public void onBackPressed()
 {
    myTask.cancel(true);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Keep a field variable in the `Fragment` called `mIsCanceled`. On back press, set it to `true` (by using a method call. Maybe write a method `cancelTask()`). Keep checking `mIsCanceled` in the asynchronous task and exit if true.

Answer (score 0):

Cancelling a task:
A task can be cancelled at any time by invoking cancel(boolean). 
Invoking this method will cause subsequent calls to isCancelled() to return true. After invoking this method, onCancelled(Object),
 instead of onPostExecute(Object) will be invoked after doInBackground(Object[]) returns.
 To ensure that a task is cancelled as quickly as possible, you should always check the return value of isCancelled() periodically from doInBackground(Object[]), 
if possible (inside a loop for instance.)